# Exception caught even value is true?

Tags: python, exception, iteration, python-3.3

I am currently attempting to write a code that iterates through a sequence (x), searching for a word that the user inputs.

Below is the code.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
i = -1
while True:
    s = input("Enter a word to search: ")
    if s != "Quit":
        try:
            while i < len(x):
                i = x.index(s, i+1)
                print("found at index", i)
        except ValueError:
            print("Not found")
        i = -1
    else:
        break
print("Goodbye")
```

The above code works fine through the iteration, but will always return the ValueError after iterating through the sequence. I attempted to rectify this by adding:

```
while i < len(x):
```

thinking the iteration would stop once it reached the end of the sequence, but it continues to throw the exception after returning the found values from the sequence.

For instance, if user enters "9", what is returned is:

```
found at index 8
Not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to find *all* occurrences, but you won't find a next occurrence past the last:

```
>>> 'abc'.index('a', 0)
0
>>> 'abc'.index('a', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

You'd need to set a flag to indicate that you found at least one match, because the exception is going to be thrown for any number of matches:

```
i = -1
try:
    found = False
    while i < len(x):
        i = x.index(s, i+1)
        print("found at index", i)
        found = True
except ValueError:
    if not found:
        print("Not found")
```

but if you are going to scan the whole `x` list *anyway*, just use a filter:

```
matches = [i for i, value in enumerate(x) if value == s]:
if not matches:
    print('Not found')
for match in matches:
    print("found at index", i)
```

If you only need to find *one* match, the first, you don't need to use a loop at all:

```
try: 
    print("found at index", x.index(s))
except ValueError:
    print("not found")
```

as there is no need to loop over the starting position then.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is perfect, worked like a charm. Though I also got the original code to work by altering `while i < len(x):` to `while i+1 < len(x)` and then adding `i += 1` after `print("found at index", i)`.

Comment: Actually, the first method is perfect, but the second method produces result of -1 index for all searches.

Comment: Which method? The `found` flag, the list comprehension with `enumerate()` or the straightforward `.index()` for just the first match?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you always get a `ValueError` is because you always continue iterating through items in the list *until* you get a `ValueError`. You need to include some sort of condition inside your inner `while` loop so that it exits if it finds an element. Better yet, do the edit I posted below.

Instead of this:

```
try:
    while i < len(x):
        i = x.index(s, i+1)
        print("found at index", i)
except ValueError:
    print("Not found")
i = -1
```

Try this:

```
try: 
    print("found at index", x.index(s))
except ValueError:
    print("not found")
```

Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Get a count first and then get the indexes of the occurrences if you want locations of multiple occurrences in the list

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
n = 0
while True:
    s = input("Enter a word to search: ")
    if s != "Quit":
        n = x.count(s)
        if s == 0:
            print('not found')
        else:
            i = -1
            while n > 0:
                print('found at index:', x.index(s,i+1))
                n = n - 1
    else:
        break
print("Goodbye")
```

Though there probably is a simpler way also.